# How to stream webcam on linux vps with videolan and output to html

Tags: centos, vlc, camera

It used to be quite simple to stream my webcam facing out into the yard to the world on my website. However, telstra has changed things where can't find a way to point my webcam to anything but local address.So I decided to install VLC on my VPS Centos 7 and try and somehow use that instead.

In the html page displaying my webcam I have the code:

```
<div class="box"><img alt="Webcam" height="240" src="http://10.0.0.95:8080/videostream.cgi?rate=0&amp;user=group&amp;pwd=;Resolution=320x240&amp;Quality=Standard" width="320" />
```

In the past the IP would reflect which ever dynamic IP I was currently assigned which was a bit of a headache not having a static IP but at least it worked.

Now VLC is installed on my remote server and I have tested to see if it works with the following command:

```
cvlc -vvv v4l2:///dev/video0 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=800,acodec=none}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}'
```

It can't find any video. So I am guessing it needs an IP but I am confused with port forwarding and dynamic dns how to go about this. In the first place to play the webcam stream do I need to do something like this:

`cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0:width=320:height=240:fps=12 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,scale=1}:duplicate{dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=192.186.0.1:8080}}' --noaudio &`

Replacing the IP with the current dynamic IP assigned by telstra or can I input my local IP and it will connect and play to the internet?

And finally what changes in html code to view output of VLC?